# Make @property private

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

Is there any way to make a @property private?

```
/**
 *
 * @property {Object} shouldBePrivate but how?
 * 
 */
...
```

I'm using [jsdoc3](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc)

I want to be able to generate my documentation two times, one with the private properties listed and another without the private properties listed.

Comment: You mean make the property show up as private in terms of jsdoc3? Explain what you mean by "private" because properties can't exactly be private.

Comment: http://usejsdoc.org/tags-private.html ?

Comment: Private - in what way? So the property is ignored by jsdoc?

Comment: @MarkBertenshaw yes, that is what I want, Zenith that does not work with properties. Ian why can't I document the properties as private (even though they are not in the code)? I will expanded my question to show why I want this

Answer (score 1):

Use the `@private` tag in the JSDoc. The HTML generator has an option to include or not to include private members, so you can generate your docs once with and once without.

Like this:

```
/**
 * Lore Ipsum and stuff
 * @property {foo}
 * @private
 */
```

Comment: This does not work on properties only on variables, methods, modules and namespaces. I don't want to make my whole module private, only some properties inside it.

Comment: I didn't find any documentation on that. But then again, the last codebase I worked on didn't use that tag, so I wouldn't know. I'm sorry the solution in my answer doesn't work and now I'm curious to find one that does.

Comment: Yeah I'm starting to think there is no way to do it currently.

Comment: Maybe replacing `@property` with `@private` and discarding the type and name parameters of the tag would help?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the tag @private

```
/**
 *
 * @property {Object} shouldBePrivate but how?
 * @private
 */
```

From the [Jsdoc3 documentation](http://usejsdoc.org/tags-private.html)

> The @private tag marks a symbol as private, or not meant for general
>   use. Private members are not shown in the generated output unless
>   JSDoc is run with the -p or --private switch.

So, just run

```
jsdoc --private file.js
```

or

```
jsdoc -p file.js
```

to include private symbols in the documentation of file.js, and jsdoc without options to exclude them.